# Windows 10 , Updating without a battery pack in laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery, windows-10-upgrade

I have a Razer Blade late 2013 and the battery for this laptop went bad, so i took it off and just been using the laptop plugged in. I currently have windows 7 and I want to upgrade to windows 10 however when I try to upgrade, it just restarts and doesn't give me any error code. I supposed this is happening because there is no battery in the laptop. The problem with the battery is that If i put it back in, and I have the laptop plugged in as well, the laptop crashes and shuts off and this is very common, without the battery, it works perfectly fine.

Thanks

Comment: I've never heard of a laptop not working properly without the battery.  The battery does act like a UPS, so if your wall power is winking off, that could cause this, although it would be quite a coincidence if the timing is consistent with a specific point in the installation.

Comment: I don't think you understood me very well. My laptop works wonderfully without the battery pack. So connected just to AC. The battery pack is all screw, as soon as I put it back in the laptop, it forces shut off constantly whether it still plug to AC or not. so I am trying to update Windows 10 without the battery pack in the laptop and it just doesn't do it.

Comment: I understand that your battery (or charging system?) is defective, which is why you leave the battery out, and the laptop normally works fine without the battery.  The question is, why does it restart inappropriately while you're trying to upgrade, and that could be a number of things.  It could just be coincidental, which was what my comment referred to.  Without the battery, the laptop is susceptible to momentary dips in power from the wall.  If the restarts absolutely never happen in normal use but happen reliably during upgrade, the wall power isn't likely the culprit.  (cont'd)

Comment: That would point to the upgrade.  If that's the case, your battery problem may be irrelevant to the issue, unless the battery problem is actually not the battery, itself.  There could be a defect in the charging circuit that gives the upgrade indigestion while your hardware is being analyzed.  Assuming it isn't that, the first question is: are you sure the restarts are inappropriate and not normal for the upgrade?  If they aren't normal, my wild guess would be a hardware compatibility or driver issue.  (cont'd)

Comment: So solving this is something that will require additional information and diagnostics.  Unless someone guesses right or this is a known problem for your laptop model, people won't be able to give you a definitive answer based on the available information, which is sort of the model the site is based on.  You might get some suggestions in comments for things to look at.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it happens without the battery with latest Windows 10 versions. I can confirm. 
Here is the solution. Please use
**Windows 10 Version 1803**
It can be installed without a battery but do not update further, Otherwise you will face the same problem.